# Twitter Bootstrap: Fixed header and right sidebar

Tags: header, twitter-bootstrap, fixed, sidebar

I'm trying to create layout with twitter bootstrap and I need to have rigth sidebar and header  fixed.
I should look like this demo http://jsfiddle.net/U8HGz/1/show/ but I need sidebar fixed on right side and I need to have navigation and banner image in top header, not just navbar.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: yes, I know how to do it with own css, but I thought, that it would be possible just by adding some bootstrap class.

Comment: All you have to do is switch around the span2 and span6 (or whatever it is) inside the row div.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I got it. I set it as `position: fixed` and added `class="offset6"`. Thank you for your help